# Question about the word всё

Tags: выбор-слова

Since "всё" means 'all' or 'everything', does "как всё" mean 'how is everything' or 'how are you all' or 'how is everybody'?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mix up "все" (everyone) and "всё" (everything)? These are two different words...

Answer (score 3):

- все = everyone
- всё = everything

Written Russian often disposes of the dots above Ё which can be confusing.

"Как всё" is not idiomatic Russian. If you want to say "How is everything?", simply use:

> Как дела?

If you want to greet a group of people with "Hi, how is everyone?", you may use:

> Всем привет! Как настроение?

"Как все" can be used, but not as a greeting:

> Как мама? Как папа? Как все? = How's mum? How's dad? How's everyone?

It can also mean 'like everyone (else)':

> Как поживаешь? - Как все: работаю, учусь.

Answer (score 2):

Correct.Всё refers to things, not to people (everything or all /things/).

> Всё хорошо.Everything is OK. Всё хорошо, что хорошо кончается All is well that ends well.

But since languages differ, we don't say Как всё.We ask Как дела?

But you can use it in

> Как всё случилось? How it all happened?

Don't use it with "people". There is another word "все".

Answer (score 1):

"Как всё" would mean 'how is everything'. Sounds awkward, I doubt native speakers use it often.

"Как все" would mean 'how are all (people)". Sounds a bit awkward too. A better phrasing is "Как там все" - how are they all there.

My guess is *как всё/все* is seldom used as is, usually some other words are added.

Comment: If "как все" is not a question it sounds okay. "А ты как думаешь? - Как все".